# select where not in array from multiple values in table

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, notin

I have an array with some values. I want to retrieve something from a table where the values are not equal to the ones in the array

```
$myarray_example = array(1.1,2.5);
```

Table example:

```
id   value
1     1.10
2     1.10
3     2.50
4     2.50
5     3.10
6     3.10
```

So in this example I want to get only 3.10 value

The query

```
SELECT value FROM table 
WHERE value NOT IN ($myarray_example)
```

It returns everything. If I use 'WHERE value IN..' then it returns nothing.

Does anyone know why this happen?

Comment: Because by your example array, these look like `string`/`varchar` values, and  `1.1` <> `1.10` and `2.5` <> `2.50`, thus, you get every row.

Comment: Hello, just to clarify, I am passing numbers. It was just a mistake in my post. Both numbers in array and in table are float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = " SELECT value FROM table ";
$query .= " WHERE value NOT IN ( ";

$count = 0;
foreach($myarray as $item) {
    $query .= $item;
    if ($count != count($myarray) - 1)
        $query .= ",";
    $count++;
}

$query .= ")";
```

Comment: Hello thanks. I have used something similar to what you just suggested and it works.